# python dict loop with all parent keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python, need help.

I got a dict.

```
categories = {
        'Private_Life': {
            'Shopping': {
                'Shopping': 'Торгово-развлекательные центры',
                'Cleaning_Agents': 'Хозтовары, бытовая химия',
                'Clothing_footwear': 'Одежда, обувь, аксессуары',
                'Domestic_Appliances': 'Бытовая техника',
                'Consumer_Electronics': 'Аудио-, видео-, фототехника',
                'Tools': 'Инструменты',
                'General': 'Универсальное',
                'Other': 'Прочее',
            },
            'Cooking': {
                'Grocery_stores': 'Продуктивные магазины',
                'Tobacco': 'Табак',
                'Soft_drinks': 'Безалкогольные напитки'
            },
            'Holidays': {
                'Gifts': 'Подарки',
                'February23': {
                    'Gifts': 'Подарки'
                },
                'Fancy_dress': 'Карнавальные костюмы',
                'Firework': 'Фейерверки'
            },
            'Beauty': {
                'Perfumery': 'Парфюмерия',
                'Jewelry': 'Украшения',
                'Make_up': 'Косметика'
            },
            'Other': 'Прочее'
        },
        'Automobiles': {
            'Parts': {
                'Online_shops': 'Интернет магазины',
                'Tyres': 'Шины и диски',
                'Spare_Parts': 'Автозапчасти',
                'Chemicals': 'Автохимия и автокосметика',
                'Car_Navigators': 'Автонавигаторы'
            }
        },
        'Sports': {
            'Shopping': {
                'Sports_feed': 'Спортивное питание',
                'Sports_shops': 'Спортивные магазины',
                'Skis_snowboards': 'Лыжи, сноуборды',
                'Sportswear': 'Спортивная одежда, обувь',
                'Rollers,_skateboards': 'Ролики, скейтборды',
                'Bicycles': 'Велосипеды',
                'Simulators': 'Тренажоры'
            },
            'Summer': {
                'Bikes': 'Велосипеды',
                'Shoot': 'Стрельба',
                'Ping_pong': 'Настольный теннис'
            },
            'Extreme': {
                'Rollers': 'Роллерспорт и скейтбординг',
                'Snowboarding': 'Сноубординг'
            }
        }
    }
```

Those are paths. I need to loop every dict element and get all nested keys. I am expecting to get array.

I tried this way:

```
   def get_category_paths(self, categories):
        result = []

        for key, value in categories.items():
            path = key

            if isinstance(value, dict):
                path += '/'
                path += self.get_category_path(value)

                return path

            result.append(self.host + path + self.query_parameters)

        return result
```

But thats wrong.

Thats what im trying to get:
Private_Life/Shopping/Shopping
Private_Life/Shopping/Cleaning_Agents

and so on by every nested keys

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your recursion is off. The code that you have shared is not complete so can't help there.

But this is what you can do to get what you are looking for:

```
def get_all_keys(dict_item, key_base=''):
    all_paths = []
    if isinstance(dict_item, dict):
        for key in dict_item:
            if key_base:
                new_key = key_base + "/" + key
            else:
                new_key = key
            all_paths.extend(get_all_keys(dict_item[key], new_key))
    else:
        if key_base:
            all_paths.append(key_base)
    return all_paths

get_all_keys(categories)
```

output:

```
['Automobiles/Parts/Spare_Parts',
 'Automobiles/Parts/Chemicals',
 'Automobiles/Parts/Car_Navigators',
 'Automobiles/Parts/Tyres',
 'Automobiles/Parts/Online_shops',
 'Private_Life/Holidays/Gifts',
 'Private_Life/Holidays/February23/Gifts',
 'Private_Life/Holidays/Firework',
 'Private_Life/Holidays/Fancy_dress',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Tools',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Cleaning_Agents',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Clothing_footwear',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Domestic_Appliances',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Shopping',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/General',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Consumer_Electronics',
 'Private_Life/Shopping/Other',
 'Private_Life/Cooking/Soft_drinks',
 'Private_Life/Cooking/Grocery_stores',
 'Private_Life/Cooking/Tobacco',
 'Private_Life/Other',
 'Private_Life/Beauty/Make_up',
 'Private_Life/Beauty/Jewelry',
 'Private_Life/Beauty/Perfumery',
 'Sports/Extreme/Snowboarding',
 'Sports/Extreme/Rollers',
 'Sports/Summer/Ping_pong',
 'Sports/Summer/Bikes',
 'Sports/Summer/Shoot',
 'Sports/Shopping/Sportswear',
 'Sports/Shopping/Sports_shops',
 'Sports/Shopping/Skis_snowboards',
 'Sports/Shopping/Rollers,_skateboards',
 'Sports/Shopping/Sports_feed',
 'Sports/Shopping/Simulators',
 'Sports/Shopping/Bicycles']
```